# Audio CMSampleBuffer format

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

What is the data stored in CMSampleBuffer when using AVCaptureAudioDataOutput? It delivers CMSampleBuffers via delegate method `–captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` but what's inside CMSampleBuffer? PCM or compressed? What are the samplerates, number of channels, etc.? How this can be used for streaming audio from device?
Googling for several hours didn't helped me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

looks like you can get the ASBD this way:

```
sampleBuffer->
  CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription ->
    CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription
```

then the ASBD will detail the frame sizes, if it is compressed, endianness, etc.

To demonstrate this (with no error checking) and get the sample rate:

```
CMSampleBufferRef cmSampleBuffer = ...;

CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription =
  CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(cmSampleBuffer);

const AudioStreamBasicDescription* const asbd =
  CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(formatDescription);

double sampleRate = asbd->mSampleRate;
```

Comment: thanks! i used just `CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription` and it showed all the info i'm wondering

Comment: and is it possible to configure `AVAudioOutput` with different parameters that i receive?

Comment: @peetonn you're welcome. regarding your question: I'm not sure if you mean `AudioOutputUnit`, `AVAudioPlayer`, or `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` when you say `AVAudioOutput`. I grew up on the Core and AU layers; I'd guess that it is whatever they want to provide, to avoid conversion overhead. It's worth searching here.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```swift
let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)
let asbd = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(formatDescription!)
let sampleRate = asbd?.pointee.mSampleRate
```